# Using multiple GSP templates/skins with Grails multi-tenant-core plug-in?

Tags: grails, skinning, gsp, multi-tenant

I have an application that uses the grails multi-tenant-core plug-in to host multiple versions of a site.  I want to be able to create custom GSPs for each site beyond what simple skinning will allow me to do.  Essentially, I want to be able to have my `grails-app/views` folder look something like:

```
views
|
|__template1
|  |
|  |__layouts
|  |  |
|  |  |__main.gsp
|  |  
|  |__controller1
|     |    
|     |__index.gsp
|
|__template 2
   |
   |__layouts
   |  |
   |  |__main.gsp
   |  
   |__controller1
      |    
      |__index.gsp
```

And then configure a specific tenant to use a specific set of GSPs.  I am using a DNS resolver that's persisted in my database, so I could presumably add a property to the `DomainTenantMap` domain class that assigns a `templateDir` property to a particular tenant and sprinkle conditional logic all over the place in my GSPs and controllers. (followed by that 'can't...get...clean' feeling)

I haven't had any success finding an existing plug-in that provides this functionality.  The other options I have considered seem to involve customizing fairly core pieces of grails (render tag, template engine, etc.) which makes me nervous.

I realize this is a fairly broad question; both specific solutions and general suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I found another possible approach by creating a plug-in and meta-programming on a new method:

```
def configureTemplateRenderer(application, applicationContext) {
    for (controllerClass in application.controllerClasses) {

        controllerClass.metaClass.newRender = { args ->
            println 'something'
            if(args.view) {
                args.view = "/somedir/${args.view}"
            }
            if(args.template) {
                args.template = "/somedir/${args.template}"
            }
            delegate.render(args)
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a proof of concept to see if I can invoke the standard `render` method through my new one (I can).  Ideally, I could override the `render` method entirely to modify the `args.view` and `args.template` property based on some sort of tenant/template mapping (not shown).  However, I haven't been able to override the `render` method successfully so this solution is really only marginally better than just sprinkling in some path variable to calls to `render`.

**A Solution!**

I ended up creating a separate plug-in that essentially boils down to overriding the render method with one that checks a tenant/template map.  Still testing but so far it looks promising, here's the gist of it:

```
def overrideRender = { application ->
    for (controllerClass in application.controllerClasses) {
        def original = controllerClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod("render", [Map] as Class[])
        def originalRender = original.getClosure()

        controllerClass.metaClass.originalRender = originalRender

        controllerClass.metaClass.render = { Map atts ->
            def templatePath = // some code to lookup against a TenantTenantMap
            if(templatePath) {
                if(atts.view) {
                    atts.view = "${templatePath}${atts?.view}"
                }
                if(atts.template) {
                    atts.template = "${templatePath}${atts?.template}"
                }
            }
            delegate.originalRender(atts)
        }
    }
}
```

The only downside is that I have to use a slightly uglier directory structure than I wanted:  `views/controller/$template/action` instead of combining all the template gsps together under `views/$template/controller/action`.  I think I can live with that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used:

```
def overrideRender = { application ->
    for (controllerClass in application.controllerClasses) {
        def original = controllerClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod("render", [Map] as Class[])
        def originalRender = original.getClosure()

        controllerClass.metaClass.originalRender = originalRender

        controllerClass.metaClass.render = { Map atts ->
            def templatePath = // some code to lookup against a TenantTenantMap
            if(templatePath) {
                if(atts.view) {
                    atts.view = "${templatePath}${atts?.view}"
                }
                if(atts.template) {
                    atts.template = "${templatePath}${atts?.template}"
                }
            }
            delegate.originalRender(atts)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing your own Spring ViewResolver: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html